# Copy autoincrement value to another column on insert?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

Basically I have a table that versions products,

so it has two columns of interest, `id | product_id`

`id` is an `autoincrement` column,
`product_id` is just an `int`

When a product is first created the `product_id` comes from the `id`,
When the product is edited we duplicate the row, so the `product_id` is the same, but the id is different. so when we first create the product we do two queries,

insert, then `update table whatever set product_id = id where id = {the insert id}`

This works, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it in one query?

Note we only have access to insert, update, delete. no triggers or stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
update table whatever set
product_id = id
where id = last_insert_id()
```

Comment: That's essentially what we are doing, but I was wondering if there was a way to link the two values during the insert?

Comment: You can query a catalog table to find the next increment value. I forget which one it is

Comment: This is not an answer to question asked

Answer (score 0):

This is the single query:

```
insert into whatever 
set product_id = last_insert_id() + 1;
```

Comment: There is no guarantee this will work if you have more than one table where you are inserting rows.