# sqlite3 - copy autoincrement field to other column on INSERT

Tags: triggers, sqlite, auto-increment

Is there a more performant way to copy the autoincrement field value to another field after row insert?
I'd like to make it automatic with triggers, but I haven't enough knowledge with them to be sure of my code.

[this answer (for mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563419/copy-autoincrement-value-to-another-column-on-insert) doesn't count for it is in the query, and i don't know if it would work with multiple rows

this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commenti ( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  content TEXT COLLATE NOCASE, 
  idcommento INTEGER REFERENCES commenti (id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

and this is the trigger i'm using: **it copies `id` (the autoincrement field) into `idcommento`** only if the value is null in the query.

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_comment_to_self AFTER INSERT ON commenti
WHEN NEW.idcommento IS NULL 
BEGIN
  UPDATE commenti SET idcommento = NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

I don't know if I can use some sort of easy `NEW.idcommento = NEW.id` istead of searching every time in all the table...

Comment: You want to copy the auto-increment value to another row in the same table?  How is that row identified in order to do the insert/update?

Comment: @Droppy in sqlite3 (as well in mysqlite) using INSERT gives you the NEW object which identify the current inserted row - and its current values. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: I mean, `NEW` is available only in the `TRIGGER`

Comment: No, I understand what an auto-increment column is, however I don't understand where you want this value copied to.

Comment: @Droppy  it copies `id` (the autoincrement field) into `idcommento` only if the value is null in the query. it is the same table `commenti`. it is the very same row just added.

Comment: The answer is "no". And did you actually measure it?

Comment: @CL. what should I had measured?

Comment: @CL. well, if i had another solution to benchmark i could do the performance measure, but you said there's no other solution other than that...